# Angular 11 `ng serve` with Node 14 throw error

Tags: node.js, angular

I have an issue which only occur If I use node > 12. I'm using node 14 and the following error is thrown:

```
Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)...events.js:377
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:209:20)
Emitted 'error' event on ClientRequest instance at:
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:475:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21) {
  errno: -54,
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read'
}
```

Anyone have an idea what could it be or how do I check what is causing this issue?

Comment: I don't imagine there's much more to be done besides "keep Node version and packages used in the project compatible" (i.e. either run on older Node - nvm helps with that - or update Angular version).